# Метод indexOf()

Tags: java, методы

После преобразования массива чисел типа int в строку методом Arrays.toString(); перестал работать метод indexOf(). То есть при выполнении такого кода на экран всегда выводится -1. Как это исправить?

```
int n = 10;        
int[] mass = new int[n];
int a = 0, b = 10;
//fill in the mass with random numbers
for(int i=0; i < n; i ++){
    mass[i] = a + (int)(Math.random()*b);
}
String str = Arrays.toString(mass);
System.out.println(str.indexOf(mass[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Читаем [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

Если вы в indexOf() передаёте int, функция считает его как код символа.

Вам необходимо преобразовать int в строку и передавать в метод её.

Вызывайте так:

```
System.out.println(str.indexOf(Integer.toString(mass[0])));
```

Или так:

```
System.out.println(str.indexOf(String.valueOf(mass[0])));
```

Или так:

```
System.out.println(str.indexOf(mass[0] + ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведите аргумент поиска к строке:

```
System.out.println(str.indexOf(mass[0] + "")); // 1
```

---

Обратите внимание на особенность выбранного метода сериализации массива:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(mass);
System.out.println(str); // "[3, 5, 8, 3, 0, 5, 3, 4, 0, 3]"
```

Если это не то, что вам нужно, попробуйте другой метод:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(mass.length);
for (int i : mass) {
  sb.append(i);
}
String s = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s);  // "3583053403"
```

Comment: окей, а почему тогда если после строки

    String str = Arrays.toString(mass);
добавить сортировку массива mass и тогда вызвать метод 

    str.indexOf(mass[0]+"")
то на экран выводится число которое больше 10, хотя в массиве то 10 символов было?

Comment: Эх, если бы) Сейчас добавлю немного в ответ

Comment: а можно как-то получить строку типа "3583053403" без цикла?

Comment: удалить через replace запятые, пробелы и квадратные скобки? =)

Comment: Был ещё по моему апачевский `StringUtils.join`

Comment: Лучше задайте новый вопрос